# Python rtree and parallelized code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, rtree

I'm trying to parallelize with `multiprocessing.Pool()` some processes that involve queries of R-trees. In the non-parallel procedure, it works as expected.

But when I try to do it in parallel (even with an example of running only 1 process in 1 core) the same query returns empty results.

I'm really puzzled about this, it goes beyond any logic for my understanding.

EDIT

Here is the simplest example that I could reproduce:

```
from multiprocess.pool import Pool
from rtree import index
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx = index.Index()
        left, bottom, right, top = (0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
        self.idx.insert(0, (left, bottom, right, top))

    def test(self, a):
        print(list(self.idx.intersection((1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0))))

b = Test()
p = Pool()
res = p.map(b.test, range(3))
b.test(1)
```

output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[0]
```

Comment: can you provide more info on your data, your query and your libraries?

Comment: The data are two shapefiles, one with smaller polygons another with bigger ones, and i just retrieve the small polygons in each bigger one. The query is just a simple `list(idx.intersection(big_pol.bounds))`, and I use Python's `Rtree` and `multiprocessing.Pool()`. The index is not passed as a parameter, so there is no problem with pickle.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `rtree` is a ctypes wrapper around `libspatialindex`, and `pickle` has no way of storing the pointer to the rtree in memory.

You could instead store the index to disk:

```
from multiprocess.pool import Pool
from rtree import index

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self, a):
        self.idx = index.Index('./rtree.idx')
        print(list(self.idx.intersection((1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0))),)

idx = index.Index('./rtree.idx')
left, bottom, right, top = (0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
idx.insert(0, (left, bottom, right, top))
idx.close()

b = Test()
p = Pool()
res = p.map(b.test, range(10))
```

Comment: I'm sure this is the way to go, and your example works as expected, but I can't manage to make it work in my real case. When I try to open the dictionary i get this error: `rtree.core.RTreeError: Error in "Index_Create": Spatial Index Error: InvalidPageException: Unknown page id 1`

Comment: Or it opens but the bounds are completely wrong: `<class 'list'>: [1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308]` I'm debugging trying to see what goes wrong, but I can't understand it.

Comment: I bet it's because rtree isn't threadsafe: https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/53

Comment: Also see https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/issues/71

Comment: I tried also to create a new index in place everytime ( thinking that the overhead of computing it thousands of times would be less than being able to be computing 64 at the same time) but still, I get empty responses to queries. So it does not crash, but it doesnt work either. I guess I will have to just give up with this.

Comment: You could try the pure Python implementation: https://github.com/Rhoana/pyrtree. Then you could pickle the index.

Comment: I'll check it out in detail in the future, since this was not a critical requirement, and I'll let know. Thanks!